# symfony2 / doctrine2 flush createas a select after delete

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm removing an entity with these commands:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->remove($exclusivedeal->getPicture());
$exclusivedeal->setPicture();
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
$this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->commit();
```

The picture Attribute is a ManyToOne relation to the picture entity.
The picture Entity has a function that is called via the postremove Annotation to remove the picture physically from the filesystem. The Flush() operation is doing the sql statements. After the delete Statement, an select statement is called too. This creates the following error:

```
[2012-06-07 10:06:46] request.CRITICAL: Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: Entity was not found. (uncaught exception) at C:\xampp\htdocs\forum\app\cache\dev\doctrine\orm\Proxies\__CG__DankeForumBundleEntityPicture.php line 32 [] []
```

When i change the annotation to preRemove, everything is fine, but this can't be the solution. I'm doing the same operation on an other Entity with a relation to the Picture Entity.

When i set the cascade remove annotation, the same problem is happened.

Has anyone an idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It sounds to me that your deleting something that is needed to reference the image on the filesystem. Why wouldn't you perform this action preRemoval of the Entity itself?

Comment: Do you mean the action which i perform at postRemove? The onlye reference on the image is the entity which I'm working with.

Comment: So if you delete that entity, how would you reference your image?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it gave me a lot of headaches trying to solve the problem. I finally found the [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/712).
The [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) on the symfony website for handling file uploads with doctrine has been updated to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this exact same problem and found the issue in my case was because I was using both cascade={"all"} (i.e 'remove') and onDelete="CASCADE".

Changing the cascade to "persist" solved it and Im now able to delete entities with image associations.